# Running a background task continuously in Django

Tags: python, django

I am running a server in Django,which is taking values continuously. The function used forever loop in it, when I call that function it never gets out of the loop.

**My problem** - I want to take values continuously from the server and use it afterwords wherever I want.

I tried threading, what I thought I could do is make a background task which keeps on feeding the database and when I want to use I can take values from it. But I dont know how to do this

```
    ip = "192.168.1.15"

    port = 5005

    def eeg_handler(unused_addr, args, ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5):

        a.append(ch1)

        print(a)

    from pythonosc import osc_server, dispatcher

    dispatcher = dispatcher.Dispatcher()

    dispatcher.map("/muse/eeg", eeg_handler, "EEG")

    server = osc_server.ThreadingOSCUDPServer(
        (ip, port), dispatcher)

    # print("Serving on {}".format(server.server_address))

    server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: @cagrias is there any example i could refer to?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [Management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-management-commands/)

With a **Management command** you can acces to your database in the same way you accesss to it through Django.

Then you can schedule this command from cron or you can make this run forever because it will not block your application.

Another [guide](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/08/27/how-to-create-custom-django-management-commands.html) to write management command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use django-background-tasks, a database-backed worked queue for django. You can follow their installation instructions from [here](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#installation).

A sample background task for your case would be:

```py
from background_task import background

@background(schedule=60)
def feed_database(some_parameter):
    # feed your database here
    # you can also pass a parameter to this function
    pass
```

All you need is to call `feed_database` from regular code to activate your background task, which will create a Task object and stores it in the database and run this function after 60 seconds.

In your case you want to run this function infinitely, so you can do something like this:

```py
feed_database(some_parameter, repeat=60, repeat_until=None)
```

This will run your function once in 60 seconds, infinitely.

They also provide a django management command, where you can give run commands to your tasks (if you don't want to start your task from your code), by using `python manage.py process_tasks`.

Comment: Can we make the background task function to render a page, replacing the current page?

Comment: You can prepare a page in the task and save it in db, but as this is a background task you can not render it.

Comment: _stores it in the database and run this function after 60 seconds_ !!! . **Django background task do not trigger itself unless you are running the ./manage.py process_task**